# Oracle linked server invalid table name

Tags: linked-server

i have created a linked server from sql server and i am now trying to access the table in oracle using the following trigger to insert data into oracle. i cannot refer the table name in oracle. getting the intellisense as invalid tablename.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ifs_limss  ON  Culligan_Dev.dbo.C_LIMS_IFST   AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO IFS.IFSAPP.C_LIMS_IFS
    (id, [name])

SELECT I.id, I.[name]
FROM INSERTED AS I

-- Insert statements for trigger here

END
GO
```

Comment: Post error message. Post Oracle `CREATE TABLE`. Most likely,  you have a case issue.

Comment: it says invalid object name :IFS.IFSAPP.C_LIMS_IFS, the linked servername is IFS. and the schema name is IFSAPP the table to which i need to insert is C_LIMS_IFS

Comment: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "IFS" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7312, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "IFS". A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema.

Answer (score 0):

With a linked server reference you must use the four part name format, for instance `SELECT * FROM server.database.schema.object`. In your example it will be looking for an object called `IFSAPP.C_LIMS_IFS` in a *local* database called `IFS`. If that is your database name then you need to prepend the server name, if that is the linked server name then you need to insert the database name after it.

In some linking schemes you attach directly to one database not the whole server, in which case you can leave the database to default, but you must give all four parts just with that one blank, perhaps `IFS..IFSAPP.C_LIMS_IFS` is what you need.

To get better help you need to edit some further detail into your question:

- What process did you follow to link the servers? Perhaps include the SQL server statements, with authentication detail removed of course, or a screenshot of you used a GUI.
- What are the server, databases, and schema names, in Oracle, and the name you have to the looked server in SQL Server? (I've tried to guess a bit from your current SQL statements but if they are wrong my guess may be). Including the connection details mentioned above may implicitly include this information.

Also, I'm not sure I would expect intellisense to work well over linked servers so perhaps be wary of relying on that.

Comment: When you say server.database.schema.object, the server is the database ip or host name i guess. database is the name of the db, schema is the username and object is the tablename. if you have any real example of it please post it with example.

Comment: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "IFS" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7312, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid use of schema or catalog for OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "IFS". A four-part name was supplied, but the provider does not expose the necessary interfaces to use a catalog or schema.

Comment: @Arif - edit the question to include the information already requested (click the "edit" link and add update that way, rather than adding it as comments) or I can be of no further help.